# JTable popupMenu for specific row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, popupmenu

i have a JTable with a popupMenu:

```
    final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem addItem = new JMenuItem("Add Movie");
    JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete Movie");

    addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.addRow(new Movie("", 0, "", "", null, "DE"));
        }
    });
    deleteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object frame = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) frame, "Movie wurde gelöscht");
        }
    });

    popupMenu.add(addItem);
    popupMenu.add(deleteItem);
    table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

adding a Movie works fine now, but i also want to delete a Movie (delete a Row + delete Movie Object out of my list)
How can i now which row the cursor was, when i clicked "Delete Movie" ?
How do i do that?

I tried to do it with this:

```
    deleteItem.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
                JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = source.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
                int column = source.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );

                if (! source.isRowSelected(row))
                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
        }
    });
```

But i get the following Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JMenuItem cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTable
```

Thank you guys =)

Comment: I figured it out, but can't answer my question, because of not enough reputation.

Comment: Your source object of the event isn't JTable , get link to the JTable from object of class, not from event .